# Displaying distinct columns and non-distinct column in one table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 Tables one that contains the user's info (including Log_Name), the logs (in which you can find Login) and the evaluation (if the user answered the 'evaluation' or not). All are connected by user_id field.

I want to output it in php in this manner:

[image]

Can you help me in solving this.

**EDIT:**
Someone suggested that I loop first Log_Name and inside that loop, I'll loop the Login then display them in a table. But I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Duplicated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476653/creating-blank-row-for-repeating-row

Comment: @w0rldart it's a different question. as you can see, this one concerns sql whike the other one is for displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once "common.php";

    $sql = "SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(log.date) as login_date FROM user INNER JOIN log ON log.user_id = user.id INNER JOIN evalution ON evalution.user_id = user.id GROUP BY user.id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<table width="40%" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Log_Name</td>
        <td>Login</td>
        <td>Evalution</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo str_replace(",","<br/>",$row['login_date']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['evalution']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

GROUP_CONCAT(log.date) will return comma separated date listing then you can display it as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest getting rid of the idea of `DISTINCT` and just use an `ORDER BY` clause.  You can then group on the front end by checking to see when the relevant group changes.  There is likely also a trick using the MySQL `GROUP BY` but it wouldn't translate to other RDBMS's.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the reasoning between putting Evaluation as a different table? Anyway:

```
SELECT u.Log_Name, l.log_time, e.evaluation FROM users_info u LEFT JOIN logs l ON l.user_id = u.user_id LEFT JOIN evaluation e ON e.user_id = u.user_id WHERE u.user_id = 'id'
```

After that you will just display the needed table with HTML rowspan.

Comment: i put evaluation on a different table because they can login many times per day but they have to answer evaluation once. Thanks! :)

Comment: how to display this? sorry! :'(