# Creating blank row for repeating row

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying distinct columns and non-distinct column in one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472423/displaying-distinct-columns-and-non-distinct-column-in-one-table)

I have 3 tables. One is `userinfo` (which where you can find `Name`), then `logs` for login details and `evaluation` for user evaluation of the activity. They are connected by the field `attendee_id`.

When I joined them it gives me this output:

[image: Actual Output]

What I want is to have an output like this:

[image: Desired Results]

When I use GROUP BY Name it returned only one row for each and not returning other data.

Comment: can you provide some sample data

Comment: Well it's obvious that this will be result. You have to run a second query for the datetime for each user.

Comment: @HerpaMoTeH what do you mean?

Comment: @bayan0926 In the first table your query makes the result return user,date,evaluation. What you need to do is run the query with Group By and then for each row in the first query you should run a query that only returns datetime.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this. In this example I have hard coded the `$rows` array, but you can replace that with your array of rows from the database.

```
<?php

$rows = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Juan',
        'login' => '09:00:01',
        'evaluation' => 'Yes'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Juan',
        'login' => '09:00:02',
        'evaluation' => 'Yes'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Juan',
        'login' => '09:00:03',
        'evaluation' => 'Yes'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Jose',
        'login' => '09:00:04',
        'evaluation' => 'No'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Jose',
        'login' => '09:00:05',
        'evaluation' => 'No'
    )
);

?>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Login</th>
    <th>Evaluation</th>
</tr>
<?php
    $prevName = '';
    foreach($rows as $row):
        if($prevName == $row['name']) {
            $name = '';
        } else {
            $name = $prevName = $row['name'];
        }
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['login']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['evaluation']); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Reminder: Solution based on "previous check" (`if($prevName == $row['name'])`) will be valid only when data will be sorted by `$row['name']`

Comment: @MFix if you were sorting on anything other than the name then the blank name presentation style would not be appropriate at all.

Comment: I'd have voted this up if it weren't for the messy mixing of PHP and inline HTML

Comment: @symcbean that is a simple method of templating. It isn't messy or inline anything. It is a clear separation of presentation and logic/data access.

Comment: @MrCode: true. As I wrote this "reminder" I wanted to make sure that he will add ORDER BY to his query (which may be inefficient in some cases) or user array_multisort so he will avoid troubles. There is also another possibility to  do different check in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this a few times and gave up. In the end, I formatted the output in PHP by checking if the value for 'name' in the current row is different to the previous one:

```
<?php
//Assume the query has been done
//...
$lastName='';
echo '<table>';
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
{
    if ($row['name']!=$lastName)
    {
        $lastName=$row['name'];
    } else
    {
        $row['name']='';
    }
    echo '<td>'.implode('</td><td>',$row).'</td>;
    echo '<tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

It's not pretty but it'll get you the result you want. You can tart it up by